# replace content of div with another div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
    
    replaceContentInContainer= function(target,source,t){
           $(t).closest('.ola').find(target).html=$(t).closest('.ola')).find(source).html;
 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-container">
    <div class="row  content-data ">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 ola">
            <div class="changeable-div">
                <div class="voters-info">
                    <div class="voting-options row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs agree-disagree">
                            <a href="#" onclick="replaceContentInContainer('changeable-div', 'afcA',this)">AGREE</a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="replaceContentInContainer('changeable-div', 'afcD',this)">DISAGREE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="afcA" style="display:none">
                Add a reason for Agreeing 
            </div>
            <div class="afcD" style="display:none">
                Add a reason for Disagreeing
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to replace the content of "changeable-div" with either "afcA" or "afcD" OF THE SAME "QUESTION-CONTAINER" depending on the link clicked . I have removed some unnecessary code however the div structure is the same(in case this problem has to be solved by dom-traversal). I cant use "id" anywhere because this question container is repeated several times in my html body.

Answer (score 0):

this syntax is wrong `$(t).closest('.ola').find(target).html=$(t).closest('.ola')).find(source).html;`

you should use instead

```
var sourceHtml = $(t).closest('.ola')).find("."+source).html();
$(t).closest('.ola').find("."+target).html(sourceHtml);
```

you can check http://api.jquery.com/html/ for more info about `.html()`